# combining select for update and limit operations,

Tags: mysql

I have a tickets table that contains all tickets to an event. All tickets are pre-created with a status of "available" During a reservation, I want to select and update N records in the table so that no other operation can access in this transaction:

```
-- get any 2 tickets that are available:
SELECT * 
from tickets 
WHERE status = 'available' 
LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE;


--(...psuedo code: if 2 records were returned, set status to 'reserved' and update other tables , 
--otherwise rollback as all tickets could not be fulfilled)
```

Using *for update*, does this guarantee that other transactions will not select the same 2 rows? I basically want to ensure that people cannot book the same ticket. Therefore I'm trying to lock the rows so that it cannot be read by other transactions

Comment: Locking the rows won't prevent other queries from **reading** the rows. It will prevent them from updating the rows. Instead of locking the rows, you might instead change the status so they won't be read with a where clause like in your query. For instance, do an update and set the status to "pending", or better yet, set it do a GUID so you can select/update the specific rows later in your process.

Comment: That makes sense! so something like: 

update tickets set status = 'pending', my_unique_id = 'ABCD' where status = 'available' limit 2; 

and I can select via my_unique_id later right? Then I can rollback if I couldn't successfully update all records defined by limit. I will try this out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

> For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any
>   associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE
>   statement for those rows.

as you see this work at row level for the query so this mean that are locked  only the 2 resulting rows